# Facebook API: how to get different resolution for Profile Pictures?

Tags: facebook, api, profile, image

How to get different resolutions for profile pictures using the facebook API? I only know the

At least in objective-c, I use the link **"http://graph.facebook.com/*[facebookId]*/picture"**, replacing the *[facebookId]* for the actually facebook id number that came from the API.

But how to get a higher resolution picture? This option gives me a very small pic.

Cheers,

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/

Check out: pic_big

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just figured it out in a blog post. You should use:

- "http://graph.facebook.com/*[facebookId]*/picture" for a very small
  picture
- "http://graph.facebook.com/*[facebookId]*/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=**400**&height=**400**" for a customizable sized picture. Just replace the values of height and width for the ones you'd like to use in your app =)